# Get all children from certain xml child element using SimpleXMLElement and xpath

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have xml like:

```
<root xmlns="urn:test:apis:baseComponents">
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>50 shades of grey</name>
    </book>
  </books>
  <disks>
    <disk>
      <name>Britney Spears</name>
    </disk>
  </disks>
</root>
```

And such php code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$books = $xml->books;
$disks = $xml->disks;

$disks->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'urn:test:apis:baseComponents');
$books->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'urn:test:apis:baseComponents');

$b_names = $books->xpath('//x:name');
```

b_names contains array with 2 values instead of 1. First holds books->book->name, second holds disks->disk->name.

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong and how could I find children of only one element?

The reason that I am using xpath instead of taking manually values using SimpleXMLElement, is that I don't know what value, which I want to search in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$books->xpath('.//x:name')` to search descendants of your `$books` variable and not descendants of the root node/document node (which the path `//x:name` does).

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks!